# How to reduce sensitive area of my touchpad?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I keep accidentally touching corners of my touchpad while typing. Can I reduce touchpad's sensitive area to avoid that?
I tried to set, for example,

```
synclient AreaLeftEdge=3000
```

which is much higher than `LeftEdge` that is `1585` but my touchpad is still sensitive over all its surface.

Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Did you see this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/221664/how-to-tune-touchpad-for-smaller-area

Comment: I did not, but I did exactly that and it had no effect